# ファイルが消せない

Tags: centos

**環境**
windows10
vagrant
virtualbox
cent-os
cyberdug
putty

**事象**
emacsの圧縮ファイル: emacs-26.1.tar.xzというものを仮想開発環境をにインストールしました。しかしインストールしたいものがこれじゃなかったことに気づき消そうとしました。しかし消せませんでした。

**やったこと**
cyberdugからファイルの権限を変更する→permission deniad
chmodで権限変更をこころみる→許可されていない操作です
rm→ダメ→許可がありません

どうすればファイルを消せるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

その操作を行う権限がない状態のように見受けられます。
`getent group sudo`で自分が`sudo`を使えるかを確認して、大丈夫なら`sudo rm (対象のファイル)`とすることでファイルを削除できると思います。

Comment: root権限というものがあること自体知りませんでした。ほんとにつらい

Answer (score -1):

**自己解決**

$ sudo: 一時的にroot権限を与える
root: 最高権限

わたしのようにunix系に無知識で同じようなめにあったひとはこちらをみたほうが速い↓
https://eng-entrance.com/linux-root

**root権限で消す方法**

```
$ sudo rm filename
```

とする